# Can I freeze chickpea curry?

Tags: freezing

I've made chickpea curry which has canned chickpeas, canned tomatoes and coconut cream (and onions, chilli powder, tumeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine any reason why you couldn't.  There's nothing in there (like a delicate fish) that could possibly lose texture or taste from being frozen.

Comment: and stewed dishes (chili, curry, actual stews) tend to freeze well

Comment: It freezes very well, in fact. I make it quite often, and like much of my food I cook a big batch and freeze portions